# Selecting records where date range is current year minus #years

Tags: oracle

I want to select and eventually delete records from a point in time earlier than current year minus "x" years.

I'm unsure of the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: You are   looking for the mos efficient way? Which ways did you consider? How many rows/bytes do you want to delete/keep? What version of Oracle do you use?

Answer (score 5):

This will delete anything three years older than January 1st of this year.

```
DELETE table_name 
WHERE change_date < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36);
```

Comment: Will this keep the current year as well? Ex: So on Aug 1st 2015, I want to keep all of 2015 (Jan 1 - Aug 1) and then all of 2014 and delete anything older.

Comment: If you use "DELETE table_name WHERE change_date < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -12);" you will delete anything older that January 1, 2014 at midnight. In other words anything from 2013 and before. -12 just means subtract 12 months from January 1st of this year.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract()` to get the actual year and compare those:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE extract(year from change_date) <= extract(year from current_date) - 5;
```

If today is 2015 this will delete anything that is in 2010 or older.

Replace the `- 5` with the "X" you want to use.

Note that `extract(year from change_date)` will not make use of an index on `change_date` itself. If performance is critical for this, you might want to create an index on the expression.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to review the `DATEADD()` function. So, a simple version is like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourData 
WHERE DateField < DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE());
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourData 
WHERE DateField BETWEEN DATEADD(yy,-5, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE());
```

So, this would give you data between 2010 and 2014. (yes you can add negative years)

Comment: You may want to ensure you understand how `BETWEEN` works.  It's typically easier to understand later on if you use `(DateField >= DATEADD(year,-5, GETDATE()) AND DateField <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))`

Comment: Also, instead of using `yy` as the parameter for `DATEADD()` you should use the full name, `year`, since its much more concise and you won't inadvertently shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: You may want to add details about how to convert that into a `DELETE` statement, as well.

Comment: The question is tagged `oracle`. There is no `dateadd()` function in Oracle.